# converting string to a valid json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string

I need to extract an object from a javascript file using node.js. I am able to read the javascript file and also able to slice the string that i need to convert as the object. Here is my code.

```
const AboutLocale = function() {
  return {
    person: {
      name: "zxczv",
      age: 25,
      gender: "male",
    },
    ar: true,
  };
};
```

I just want the person object from this file and i am able to achieve this using slice operator. Now it gives me a string that looks like this

```
  "{
    name: "man",
    age: 25,
    gender: "male",
  }"
```

I tried parsing it but it is not a valid JSON. I need help converting it into a valid object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: i tried JSON.stringify, not returning the ideal result.

Comment: What is that? Can you show us and compare it to the stringify output?

Comment: It is throwing an error in the code using stringify. but i am able to fix this problem using regex provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of regex. The first one replaces all property names with themselves, but quoted. The second one removes any commas before a closing bracket. Note that this is a very fragile solution and might break if you throw anything unexpected at it. It's better just to run the file, run the command AboutLocale, and then JSON.stringify the output into valid JSON.

```js
const input = `{
    name: "man",
    age: 25,
    gender: "male",
  }`

const input2 = `{header:"Aboutjdkahsfjk34",productShortName:"OBDX123456",version:"Version",servicePack:"Service Pack",poweredByValue:"asag",copyright:"Copyright 2006-2020",build:"Build",name:"manav"}`

const input3 = `{header:"Aboutjdka,hsfjk34",productShortName:"OBDX1,23456",version:"Version",servicePack:"Service Pack",poweredByValue:"asag",copyright:"Copyright 2006-2020",build:"Build",name:"manav"}`

fixed = input.replace(/\b(.*?):/g, "\"$1\":").replace(/,.*\n.*}/gm, "}")
fixed2 = input2.replace(/([,{])(.*?):/g, "$1\"$2\":")

let fixed3 = ""
let inAProperty = false
input3.split("").forEach((e,i) => {
  if (e === "{") fixed3 += "{\""
  else if (e === ":") fixed3 += "\":"
  else if (e === ",") fixed3 += inAProperty ? e : ",\""
  else if (e === "\"") {
    inAProperty = !inAProperty
    fixed3 += e
  } else fixed3 += e
})

console.log(fixed)
console.log(JSON.parse(fixed))

console.log(fixed2)
console.log(JSON.parse(fixed2))

console.log(fixed3)
console.log(JSON.parse(fixed3))
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me. Kind of requirement i have this file will remain unchanged.

Comment: Hey there. this regex doesn't work if i remove spaces and line breaks from the string. can you help me with the updated regex.

Comment: Hello. Try removing the `\n` from the second regex

Comment: I tried it didn't work. may be the first regex needs some changes.

Comment: Please give an example of the input you are now using.

Comment: `{header:"Aboutjdkahsfjk34",productShortName:"OBDX123456",version:"Version",servicePack:"Service Pack",poweredByValue:"asag",copyright:"Copyright 2006-2020",build:"Build",name:"manav"} ` this is my input without spaces.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a second regex to deal with input like the one you gave me

Comment: you are great with the regex, this has definitely worked for me, but the value can be anything, suppose one property is `header:"man,anv"` then this won't work.

Comment: @Manavjethani I have once again updated the answer. It would be non-trivial to use regex for it so I did not do that. The code snipped for the 3rd input may work for all 3, but I have not tested it.